how to NOT display the tab's ID as a tooltip
I'm using the DocuSign e-Sign.
I add a couple radio groups to my envelope. Each radio group has a unique ID in the groupName field. (If I didn't have this ID, then all the radio groups would collapse into a single group.)
When the signer goes to sign the document, each radio button displays a tooltip containing the radio group's ID. This isn't a problem, but it looks weird to the end user.
How do I make DocuSign NOT display this tooltip? (or at least not display the ID in the tooltip)


Just update the tooltip property of the radio group
Here is full JSON:
{"radioGroupTabs":[{"tabLabel":"Radio Group 045f6492-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f6be611512c1","conditionalParentLabel":null,"conditionalParentValue":null,"isPrefilledTab":false,"agreementType":"","agreementTypeLocked":false,"fontSize":"size9","underline":false,"italic":false,"fontColor":"black","bold":false,"font":"lucidaconsole","groupName":"Radio Group 594b11bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e0be5a2adb2f","shared":false,"name":"inbar101","tooltip":"inbar101","shareToRecipients":"","recipientId":"89560761","documentId":"1","width":0,"height":0,"radios":[{"tabLabel":"Radio Group 045f6492-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f6be611512c1","conditionalParentLabel":null,"conditionalParentValue":null,"isPrefilledTab":false,"agreementType":"","agreementTypeLocked":false,"fontSize":"size9","underline":false,"italic":false,"fontColor":"black","bold":false,"font":"lucidaconsole","groupName":"Radio Group 594b11bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e0be5a2adb2f","shared":false,"required":true,"locked":false,"name":"inbar101","selected":false,"value":"Radio1","tooltip":"inbar101","shareToRecipients":"","recipientId":"89560761","pageNumber":1,"documentId":"1","xPosition":534,"yPosition":59,"width":0,"height":0,"trackingId":"c1369","trackingid":"c1369"},{"tabLabel":"Radio Group 045f6492-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-f6be611512c1","conditionalParentLabel":null,"conditionalParentValue":null,"isPrefilledTab":false,"agreementType":"","agreementTypeLocked":false,"fontSize":"size9","underline":false,"italic":false,"fontColor":"black","bold":false,"font":"lucidaconsole","groupName":"Radio Group 594b11bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e0be5a2adb2f","shared":false,"required":true,"locked":false,"name":"inbar101","selected":false,"value":"Radio2","tooltip":"TEST TOOLTIP","shareToRecipients":"","recipientId":"89560761","pageNumber":1,"documentId":"1","xPosition":534,"yPosition":79,"width":0,"height":0,"trackingId":"c1370","trackingid":"c1370"}]}]}


Okay, that will change the tooltip to say something else instead of the ID. But is there any way to make it say nothing? (Or at least just say "Required" but nothing else?)

You can try to put an empty string or play with this different values until you get what you need.

If you put an empty string in the tooltip, it'll display the ID. (I'm using the Java SDK.) I guess I can use a zero-width space; it's a little hacky, but it achieves what I want. Thanks!
